# Nested iframe in Stripe 3DS - unable to attach to them using Selenium/Serenity

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, serenity-bdd

I'm having trouble with locating the buttons in this Stripe 3DS sandbox which appear to be 3 iframes down into the page. The layout is in the attached image.

I have tried the following:

The below results in a message that the frame cannot be found

```
        OnStage.theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(Switch.toFrame("__privateStripeFrame8499"));
        OnStage.theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(Switch.toFrame("__stripeJSChallengeFrame"));
        OnStage.theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(Switch.toFrame("acsFrame"));
```

The below results in null pointer exceptions (even with this at the top of the file)

```
@Managed
WebDriver driver;

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/iframe")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"challengeFrame\"]")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/iframe")));
```

This variant results in a casting error

```
        OnStage.theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(Switch.toFrame((WebElement) StripePaymentDetailsPage.STRIPE_IFRAME));
        OnStage.theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(Switch.toFrame((WebElement)StripePaymentDetailsPage.STRIPE_CHALLENGE_IFRAME));
        OnStage.theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(Switch.toFrame((WebElement)StripePaymentDetailsPage.STRIPE_FULLSCREEN_FRAME));
```

[image]
[image: Code Layout]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this after a few hours at it, my first discovery was that the iframes have dynamic names - I used debugging code like this to dig down

```
List<WebElement> frameList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    System.out.println("Num Frames: " + frameList.size());

    for (WebElement element : frameList) {
        String frameName = element.getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println("Frame Name is " + frameName);
    }
```

In the end I found the cancel button on a different layer to the buttons but to interact with the buttons themselves I did this:

```
  private void completeOrFail3dsAuthentication(String action) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebDriver driver = BrowseTheWeb.as(OnStage.theActorInTheSpotlight()).getDriver();
  
    // try switching to a frame
    driver.switchTo().frame(0); // cancel button
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.switchTo().frame(0); // sub frame
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.switchTo().frame(0); // frame with Complete or Fail Authentication

    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("fail")) {
        BaseTasks.waitAndClick(OnStage.theActorInTheSpotlight(), StripePaymentDetailsPage.THREE_D_S_FAIL_AUTH_BUTTON);
    } else {
        BaseTasks.waitAndClick(OnStage.theActorInTheSpotlight(), StripePaymentDetailsPage.THREE_D_S_COMPLETE_AUTH_BUTTON);
    }
    Thread.sleep(500);
    //switch back to original frame
    driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
}
```